# Javascript variables aren't updating pomodoro clock

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm trying to make a Pomodoro clock and am having trouble with my variables not updating. I created buttons that when clicked increase or decrease the Variable for Work Time but when I call my startTimer function my variable workTime is still the original value that it was initially set at. How do I make my variables update to the correct amount.

Heres a link to my Codepen. 
http://codepen.io/jerardov/pen/Xbvbpo

CSS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//variables//
workTime = 25;
time = workTime * 60;
breakLength = 5;

//update variables

$(".breakMinus").click(function() {
  if (breakLength > 0) {
    breakLength -= 1;
    $(".breakLength").text(breakLength);
  }
})
$(".breakPlus").click(function() {
  breakLength += 1;
  $(".breakLength").text(breakLength);
})
$(".workMinus").click(function() {
  if (workTime > 0) {
    workTime -= 1;
    $(".workTime").text(workTime);
    $("#time").text(workTime);
  }
})
$(".workPlus").click(function() {
  workTime += 1;
  $(".workTime").text(workTime);
  $("#time").text(workTime);
})

//click//
$(".start").click(function() {
  display = $('#time');
  startTimer(time, display);
})

//display//
$(".workTime").text(workTime);
$(".breakLength").text(breakLength);
$("#time").text(workTime);

console.log(workTime);
console.log(secondS);

//start time function//
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

});
```

HTML

```
<h1>Adjust Work Time</h1>
<div class="workTime"></div>
<button class="btn btn-success workMinus">-</button>
<button class="btn btn-success workPlus">+</button>
<h1>Break Time</h1>
<div class="breakLength"></div>
<button class="btn btn-success breakMinus">-</button>
<button class="btn btn-success breakPlus">+</button>
<h1>Clock</h1>
<div><span id="time"></span>

</div>
<button class="btn btn-success start">start</button>

<div class=""></div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mt9en6bm/

Comment: Your var `time`is not refreshed when you increase or decrease the va `workTime`, if you set `workTime * 60` as a parameter for startTimer, it looks better: http://jsfiddle.net/mt9en6bm/1/

Comment: Thank you! @DidierAupest

Comment: console.log(secondS); does not return results, because the var doesn't exists in this scope. You might consider using Id instead of class for start / breakMinus / breakPlus / workMinus / workPlus.

Comment: Thank you I  fixed that. Could you also help me for some reason when the clock reaches zero (00:00) it will restart automatically and start over? @DidierAupest

Answer (score 1):

Few flaws in the code;

1. 'timer' variable is not updated when you change the worktime/break duration. Hence when calling Start timer, it uses the original value. Hence the bug.
2. Use a JSlint to check your code for good javascript practices.
3. You need to use clearInterval() if a previous interval was set.