# Jquery Pomodoro Clock - variable doesn't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I realize there was another similar question about this [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173150/javascript-variables-arent-updating-pomodoro-clock.). However, the answers just weren't working with my own code, so I have to ask again. I want these variables "initial" and "count" to update according to the new value of pomoLength , but found no way to solve it yet. Here is a link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/quangla/pen/zrKGew)

HTML

```
<div>
  <span id="timer"></span>
  <div id="pomoLength">
    <button class="btn minus"> - </button>
    <span class="display"> 25 </span>
    <button class="btn plus"> + </button>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="start">start</button>
<button id="stop">stop</button>
<button id="reset">reset</button>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pomoLength = 25;
  var initial = pomoLength * 60;
  var breakLength = 5;
  var count = initial;
  var counter;

  $('.plus').click(function() {
    pomoLength++;
    $('.display').text(pomoLength);
  });
  $(".minus").click(function() {
    if (pomoLength == 0) return;
    pomoLength--;
    $('.display').text(pomoLength);
  });

  function timer() {
    if (count <= 0) {
      clearInterval(counter);
      return;
    }
    count--;
    displayCount(count);
  }

  function displayCount(count) {
    var hours = Math.floor(count / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor(count % 3600 / 60);
    var seconds = count % 60;

    // Format times to show double digits
    if (hours < 1) {
      hours = hours.toString();
      hours = "";
    } else if (hours < 10) {
      hours = "0" + hours.toString() + " hours ";
    };
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + minutes.toString() + " minutes " +
      seconds.toString() + " secs";
  }

  $('#start').on('click', function() {
    counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
  });
  $('#stop').on('click', function() {
    clearInterval(counter);
  });
  $('#reset').on('click', function() {
    clearInterval(counter);
    displayCount(initial);
  });

  displayCount(initial);
});
```

Comment: Here's an updated code pen. Plus/minus change initial, and reset sets the count to the new initial. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mVOzOw

Comment: You could also just move what your reset button is doing into the click events of the plus/minus

Comment: thanks guys, but the timer won't update itself after clicking plus/minus (only until I click reset button). Also I want the reset button to reset the clock back into 25 minutes (pomoLength = 25).

Comment: Ah, alright. Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PZbyee
It could be cleaned up a bit, but it now updates the timer on plus/minus and resets to 25.

Comment: thank so much Mic... if only I have enough reputation to upvote your comment!!!